# Oracle Replace char with newline

Tags: oracle, replace, plsql, newline

I am trying to replace a char in my Select with an newline. But it doenst work.

Here is the code:

```
vMsg := to_char(rec.CREATED,'HH24:MI') || ' - ' || replace(rec.FILELIST, '|', chr(13) || chr(10)) || chr(13) || chr(10) || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'Test'
```

But this does not work, it seems like Oracle replaces '|' with ' '

Example input:

> Audio.hx|Camera.hx|Circle.hx|Color.hx|Component.hx|Core.hx|Debug.hx|Draw.hx|Emitter.hx|Entity.hx|Events.hx|Game.hx|Input.hx|IO.hx|Log.hx|

Example output:

> Audio.hx Camera.hx Circle.hx Color.hx Component.hx Core.hx Debug.hx
> Draw.hx Emitter.hx Entity.hx Events.hx Game.hx Input.hx IO.hx Log.hx

What i expected:

> Audio.hx
>
> Camera.hx
>
> Circle.hx
>
> Color.hx
>
> ...

Comment: "*does not work*" is not an acceptable error description

Comment: What is the sample input and expected output?

Comment: This looks to be your client not displaying the data in the manner in which you wish it to. What are you using to view this?

Comment: vMsg is sent via email and viewed in Outlook 2013. The newlines after FILELIST work just fine.

Comment: If you wrap the result in `rawtohex(...)` you can see the actual bytes. When I do that on your string I see the `0D0A`s as expected.

Comment: If you're sending this to Outlook, maybe it's interpreting the text as markup (HTML-like) - so try replacing the carriage returns with `<BR>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works perfectly for me in `SQL*Plus` using **TRANSLATE** or **REPLACE**. If you are unable to view it properly, then it might an issue with your **client**.

For example,

---

### SQL approach

Using **TRANSLATE**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT 'Audio.hx|Camera.hx|Circle.hx|Color.hx|Component.hx|Core.hx|Debug.hx' str
  3    FROM dual
  4    )
  5  SELECT str, TRANSLATE(str, '|', chr(10)) str_newline FROM DATA
  6  /

STR                                                                 STR_NEWLINE
------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------
Audio.hx|Camera.hx|Circle.hx|Color.hx|Component.hx|Core.hx|Debug.hx Audio.hx
                                                                    Camera.hx
                                                                    Circle.hx
                                                                    Color.hx
                                                                    Component.hx
                                                                    Core.hx
                                                                    Debug.hx


SQL>
```

Using **REPLACE**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT 'Audio.hx|Camera.hx|Circle.hx|Color.hx|Component.hx|Core.hx|Debug.hx' str
  3    FROM dual
  4    )
  5  SELECT str, REPLACE(str, '|', chr(10)) str_newline FROM DATA
  6  /

STR                                                                 STR_NEWLINE
------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------
Audio.hx|Camera.hx|Circle.hx|Color.hx|Component.hx|Core.hx|Debug.hx Audio.hx
                                                                    Camera.hx
                                                                    Circle.hx
                                                                    Color.hx
                                                                    Component.hx
                                                                    Core.hx
                                                                    Debug.hx


SQL>
```

---

### PL/SQL approach

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_str VARCHAR2(4000);
  3  BEGIN
  4    v_str:= 'Audio.hx|Camera.hx|Circle.hx|Color.hx|Component.hx|Core.hx|Debug.hx';
  5    dbms_output.put_line(REPLACE(v_str, '|', chr(10)));
  6  END;
  7  /
Audio.hx
Camera.hx
Circle.hx
Color.hx
Component.hx
Core.hx
Debug.hx

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: But why do the linebreaks after replace(rec.FILELIST, '|', chr(13)) work?

Comment: I don't see the need for multiple `chr(10)` and `chr(13)`. Can you try the way I demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps:

```
declare
    v_str varchar2(1000) := 'Audio.hx|Camera.hx|Circle.hx|Color.hx|Component.hx|Core.hx|Debug.hx|Draw.hx|Emitter.hx|Entity.hx|Events.hx|Game.hx|Input.hx|IO.hx|Log.hx|';
begin
    v_str := REPLACE(v_str,'|',CHR(10));

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_str);
end;
```

Btw, why you use CHR(13)?